# ¿Como valido un input tipo radio con jquery con el mismo name o id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Este es el texto que quiero arreglar, el asunto es que no se como hacer para que me valide cada input seleccionado o  no seleccionado

```
const mostrar_respuestas = async (id_pregunta) => {
let respuestas = await obtener_pasos(id_pregunta);
//consulta_ajax(`${ruta_ambiental}obtener_repuesta`, {id_pregunta}, respuestas => {
    respuestas.forEach((elemento, index) => {
        $(`#respuesta_${id_pregunta}`).append(`
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="respuesta_${id_pregunta}" id="respuesta__${id_pregunta}_${elemento.id}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="respuesta_${id_pregunta}_${elemento.id}" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
            ${elemento.valor}
        </label><br>
        `);
    })
    $(document).on("click", "#next", function() {
        if(document.querySelector(`input[name='respuesta_${id_pregunta}']:checked`) == null) {
            MensajeConClase(`Respuesta(s) sin responder:  Para continuar debe responder todas!.`, "info", "Oops.!");
        } else {
            mostrar_preguntas2(idp);
            $("#next").text("GUARDAR");
        }
    });
//});
```

}

Comment: Creo q falta mucha información, te sugiero hacer el recorrido de bienvenida y ver el apartado "¿Como preguntar?". Te hará más sencillo elaborar una pregunta clara y será más sencillo para los usuarios poder ayudar. Además de evitar que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Mira te recomiendo que en vez de crear los inputs como cadenas de texto los crees directamente con jQuery `$('<input/>').attr('type', 'checkbox')` y luego dentro del mismo foreach puede añadir una funcion que se ejecuta ya sea por chage u onclick que obtenga el estado y muestre el msj

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo intentaré de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

No se si al final te he entendido. Me parece que lo que quieres es capturar la respuesta y verificar su resultado. ¿Es eso?

Si fuera eso dentro del `else` puedes acceder al id del boton de radio seleccionado de este modo:

```javascript
$(document).on("click", "#next", function() {
  var respuesta = document.querySelector(`input[name='respuesta_1']:checked`);
  if (respuesta == null) {
    MensajeConClase(`Respuesta(s) sin responder:  Para continuar debe responder todas!.`, "info", "Oops.!");
  } else {
    console.log(respuesta.id);
    mostrar_preguntas2(idp);
    $("#next").text("GUARDAR");
  }
});
```

Lo que debes hacer ahora es comparar ese `respuesta.id` con el resultado esperado, y modificar el codigo del `else` acorde con lo que quieras hacer.

Te dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#next", function() {
  var respuesta = document.querySelector(`input[name='respuesta_1']:checked`);
  if (respuesta == null) {
    console.log('Ningun botón de radio está seleccionado');
    //MensajeConClase(`Respuesta(s) sin responder:  Para continuar debe responder todas!.`, "info", "Oops.!");
  } else {
    console.log(respuesta.id);
    //mostrar_preguntas2(idp);
    //$("#next").text("GUARDAR");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta_1" id="respuesta_1_1">
<input type="radio" name="respuesta_1" id="respuesta_1_2">
<input type="radio" name="respuesta_1" id="respuesta_1_3">
<input type="radio" name="respuesta_1" id="respuesta_1_4">
<button id="next">
Siguiente
</button>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intentaré de esa manera